# Can't remove "synchronizing/suspect" database after removed from availability group Sql Server 2019 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

I've removed a db from a synchronous availability group.The db shows "synchronizing/suspect" as it should on the secondary. I'm trying to remove this database cannot. I have tried:

```
DROP DATABASE [db1];
```

but get "Cannot drop database "db1" because it is currently in use.". even though their are no sessions using this database.

```
ALTER DATABASE [db1] SET OFFLINE;
```

but get "ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'db1'. Try again later."

```
ALTER DATABASE [db1]
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

but get "ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'db1'. Try again later."

```
ALTER DATABASE [db1] SET EMERGENCY;
```

ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'db1'. Try again later.

This is a 24/7 production db and restarting is not a good option.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Does this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673352/5059085) help you? Summarized from the answer:

1. Run `EXEC sp_who2`.
2. Look for any open connections to the database in question.
3. Run `KILL SPID` where the SPID is of the process for that connection.

You might also find Adam Machanic's [`sp_whoisactive`](http://whoisactive.com/) helpful for locating the connection's process with additional information.

Comment: No. I can see all the locks on this secondary database and all the spids but I cant kill these spids are they are all system spids. I did add certificates and encrypted the primary server db before trying to remove the secondary db.

Comment: @SaltyTiger What happens when you try to kill one of the lock SPIDs?

Comment: I cant kill them, they're all system spids.

Comment: @SaltyTiger Right, but what happens when you try to?...do you get an error?...if so, which error?...some context would be helpful. I believe you should be able to, at least with an account that has `sysadmin` server privileges. I've manually killed Replication system processes when they were causing locking issues, I would figure Availability Groups shouldn't be much different in that regard.

Comment: I get a "db in use" when I try drop the db on the replica. these a the spids and none of them can be killed as I get "Only user processes can be killed.".


spid dbid ObjId IndId Type                                    Resource Mode
115 22 0 0 DB                                                       U GRANT
385 22 0 0 DB         [STARTUP]                             X         GRANT
404 22 0 0 DB         [HADR_STATE_MANAGEMENT]    U GRANT

Answer (score 0):

Please try to disconnect and reconnect the instance or may be even check it with other user. There could be a possibility that AlwaysOn on monitoring page is opened. Chances are high that  with a new session from a different session the issue would not come. Pls try these.